# Open GoPro Hero 11 send USB commands while connected to Android phone

Tags: gopro

I have a project in which I want to send commands (start and stop recording) to my GoPro Hero 11 from my Android (12) phone, with a self made ionic capacitor app. The setup is that the GoPro is always connected to my phone by a USB cable.

With the [Open GoPro](https://github.com/gopro/OpenGoPro) project, this should be possible. I first tried to send commands with the [HTTP API](https://gopro.github.io/OpenGoPro/http_2_0) over wifi. This works great, however, the wifi AP of the GoPro disables itself after a while. This can be turned back on over BLE, so I tried [this BLE API of Open GoPro](https://gopro.github.io/OpenGoPro/ble_2_0#commands-quick-reference), and the [ionic demo from the github page](https://github.com/gopro/OpenGoPro/blob/main/demos/ionic/file_transfer/src/app/home/home.page.ts). This again works great, I can connect to the GoPro and send commands (even the start and stop, so no need for wifi in this case). However, I again ran into some troubles. When connected by USB, the BLE doesn't seem to work anymore. Therefore, I tried to send the HTTP commands over USB, which should work according to the docs. Yet again, I found it not possible to enable the wired USB control through my phone. When I connect the GoPro to my windows pc, I could enable and use the USB commands (after downloading the [webcam driver](https://community.gopro.com/s/article/GoPro-Webcam?language=en_US)), so this means I am using the right connection and commands. When I connect the GoPro to my phone with USB, the GoPro Quik app does recognize it, so I think it should also be possible to send HTTP commands over USB from my phone. I did notice that when I connect my phone to the GoPro via USB, the GoPro first says "USB CONNECTED". I then checked my phone's connected devices > USB and saw that the USB was managed by connected device. I switched that so my device manages the USB connection. Then the GoPro shows its controls again on its screens. So this made me think that there my be another setting I should switch on my phone,  download something (like the windows driver), or need to do something code wise.

So in short: I can get the Wifi/BLE/USB commands working in some conditions, therefore I'm sure I am using the right connections and commands. I just can't get them working in the conditions I need for my project:

- can't use BLE when GoPro is connected via USB
- can't enable wired USB via Android phone
- can't enable wifi without BLE or USB

A solution to any of these would be really helpfull.

**Edit:**
I have found that the BLE does work when the GoPro is only being charged. So plugging the USB cable in an outlet instead of a device works. This helps me further, but I would still appreciate an answer for enabling wired USB via my Android phone.